# Bamboo - jmeter aggregate performance

Tags: maven, jmeter, bamboo

We are working on integrating jMeter into Bamboo (using maven/chronos) in order to automate performance tests using build scheduling and dependencies.

Before we began working on this project, IT had updated Bamboo to the latest release -- 3.1. We had our sites set on the [Bamboo JMeter Aggregator Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JMETAGG/Bamboo+JMeter+Aggregator+Plugin), but it does not yet support Bamboo 3.1. Log aggregation is important to us, but if we cannot get a visual through Bamboo at this time, we are willing to look into other option.

My questions:

- Of those of you using Bamboo, do any of you have jMeter integrated?
- Do you use any type of aggregation?
- Does anyone have any suggestions for getting a scheduled and/or on-demand look at the performance of a build (preferrably integrated into an Atlassian product)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jmeter Aggregator plugin is no longer supported and does not work with latest version of Bamboo. We use instead [SmartMeter](https://www.smartmeter.io/features#id-ci). It is compatible with Jmeter (means that you can run scripts made in/for Jmeter in it).

If you want to install it, just follow the documentation for [Bamboo integration](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-bamboo)

Aggregated report could be seen in [Trend analysis](https://www.smartmeter.io/blog/performance-trend-analysis-compare-load-test-results) in test results/reports
[image]